# Return Alamofire response from a function

Tags: ios, swift, function

```
func getStoriesNF () -> [String:Any] {

        let parameters: Parameters = ["user_id": userID]

        Alamofire.request("https://example.com/stories.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let json = response.result.value {

                    if let data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json as Data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {

                        return data

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

I am having `Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_) throws -> _' to non-throwing function type '(DataResponse<Any>) -> Void'` error.

How can I return data from this function?

Comment: Are you able to cast `data` as  `[String: Any]`?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. `Alamofire.request` is asynchronous. You need to use a closure / completion handler instead of trying to return something from your function.

Comment: I tried completion handler as well but got the same error idk why @mag_zbc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that `Alamofire.request` is an asynchronous call, so you will need to use a completion handler, like so

```
func getStoriesNF (completion: @escaping ([String : Any]?, Error?) {

    let parameters: Parameters = ["user_id": userID]

    Alamofire.request("https://example.com/stories.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let json = response.result.value {
                do {
                    if let data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json as Data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {
                        completion(data, nil)
                } catch (let error) {
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`JSONSerialization.jsonObject` needs to be contained within a `try-catch` block since it's a throwing call

Answer (score 1):

You can't return data from asynchronous call like this. You may need to handle this via completion handlers.

```
     typealias CompletionHandler = ([String:Any]? , Error?) -> ()
    func getStoriesNF (completion: @escaping CompletionHandler)  {

        let parameters: Parameters = ["user_id": userID]

        Alamofire.request("https://example.com/stories.php", method: .post, parameters: parameters).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let json = response.result.value {

                    if let data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json as Data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {

                        completion(data, nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @mag_zbc yes you are right, I've edited the code. I'd copied code from question.

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz as per the error in question and also the error statement said. completion handler should fix your issue. might be you are getting something else now.

Comment: I totally copied and pasted your answer but still having the same error

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz Edit the original question to show how you are using it, because this code is exactly what you need. And by the way, you should start with reading about asynchronous execution in Swift, because it's the very foundation of working with network calls.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below code and see if this works?

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let json = response.result.value {

                if let data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json as Data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {

                    completion(data, nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: which version of Alamofire are you using?

Comment: Latest version on pods

Comment: Show us how you are using this code, because you're doing something wrong. Completion handlers are the way to go.

Comment: I am not using this code yet I am just building the function. OK Completion handlers are the way to go but I just wanna get rid of this error : ) Error is gone if I remove "if let data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json as Data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] {
                        completion(data, nil)
                    }" partt